# Crontab and rkhunter Scheduling

Tags: cron, rkhunter

I've got a system with Ubuntu 12.04 which has rkhunter installed. Currently the rkhunter daily scan script is located in `/etc/cron.daily/rkhunter`.

Every day at 7pm EST the rkhunter script is executed and the following is added to the `/var/log/rkhunter.log` file:

`Info: Start date is Tue May 22 19:00:29 EDT 2012`

However, here are the contents of my `/etc/crontab` file:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 3   * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

If I'm reading this correctly, it should be executing at 3:25am, not 7pm. I changed it from the default of 6:25 and nothing changed when the task actually executed.

The current output of `date` matches the local time on my machine. I also have restarted cron with `sudo service cron restart` since changing the crontab.

So, what am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that ISPConfig has it's own scheduled task setup. In this file, `/usr/local/ispconfig/server/mods-available/monitor_core_module.inc.php`, there is a `_monitorRkHunter` function that was set to run the rkhunter scan at 2300 UTC.

Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other scripts located in /etc/cron.daily ? The entry in crontab is not about rkhunter in particular you see.

Maybe there are other scripts that get executed before rkhunter at 06:25.

(just a suggestion, I really have an idea).

Comment: There are other scripts including apache2, ntp, aptitude, dpkg, etc. The thing is, though, the rkhunter script fires off at 1900 hours, not 0625, no matter what I change in the `/etc/crontab` file. Shouldn't that be what defines when the `/etc/cron.daily/` tasks run?

Comment: Try adding the script in crontab by itself and not via cron.daily and see what it does.

Comment: I just added a script to `/etc/crontab/` and it executed when it was supposed to (EST time). Are there any other scheduling systems Ubuntu uses?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo crontab -l root
```

If that lists the cronjob, well, then the cronjob is schuleded for root. Try then `sudo crontab -e root` and change the schedule at will.

Comment: The rkhunter job isn't listed in the output of `crontab -l` when logged in as root. It just lists some ISPConfig tasks that run every 30 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

The cron system is actually much more complex than it appears. The entries in `/etc/crontab` run `/usr/sbin/anacron` if it is executable (`test -x ...`), and only run `run-parts` if it is not.

anacron changes the times tasks are run and can fire on wakeup for example. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#How_Anacron_is_Arranged

Comment: anacron actually isn't installed.